# Does pipe change filenames?

Tags: bash, pipe, filenames

I do this command:

```
$ locate config.yml | while read i; do sed -i '/(swipe)|(pinch)/s/[0-9].*/1/' $i; done
```

output:

```
sed: couldn't open temporary file /home/user/.config/fusuma/sedHhlVCW: Permission denied
sed: couldn't open temporary file /home/var/lib/gems/2.5.0/gems/fusuma-0.11.1/lib/fusuma/sed41YvwW: Permission denied
sed: couldn't open temporary file /var/lib/gems/2.5.0/gems/fusuma-1.10.0/lib/fusuma/sedFSNXeV: Permission denied
```

So I did with sudo (run as sudo `sudo su -> #`, but then not all files were change, and as I see from the error above, the files are temporary and with changed name (postfix of all them consist of command and random chars), does this pipe? If so why? How can I persist filenames over pipe?

```
$ uname -a
Linux user 4.19.0-9-amd64 #1 SMP Debian 4.19.118-2 (2020-04-29) x86_64 GNU/Linux

$ type sed
sed is aliased to `sed -E'
```

Comment: See https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/106663/how-to-run-a-command-that-involves-redirecting-or-piping-with-sudo -- prefixing the command with `sudo` will not cause `sed` to run under a different user

Comment: I actually did not prefix command with sudo, but rather run as sudo (with `sudo su`), like `# comand ...`

Comment: What Unix are you using, and do you know what `sed` implementation you're working with?

Comment: Did not know these information is needed, will add them to the post

Comment: You might want to replace the `$i` with `"$i"` to avoid expanding arguments

Comment: Ok, but still, quoting is not the issue i think

Comment: The `sedXXXXX` files are likely due to the implementation of `sed -i`. This usually works by writing to a temporary file and then replacing the target file, rather than writing to the target file directly

Comment: @Torin but otherwise, the result would not save, but thanks, I thought it is caused by the pipe