# pkexec with >> directing output to file

Tags: sudo, su, pkexec

If I try

```
pkexec echo -e '\nwl2k something\n' >> /etc/ax25/axports
```

in terminal to have a user add a line to a file, I get a

bash: /etc/ax25/axports: Permission denied

How do I make it so the whole command goes to pkexec - that is, ask user for sudo to make the change?

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How to run a command that involves redirecting or piping with sudo?](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/106663/how-to-run-a-command-that-involves-redirecting-or-piping-with-sudo)

Answer (score 0):

> ```
> pkexec echo -e '\nwl2k something\n' >> /etc/ax25/axports
> bash: /etc/ax25/axports: Permission denied
> ```

Output redirects have the permissions of the user who invoked the shell, not the command that produced the output. See https://unix.stackexchange.com/a/6714/411962.

Instead pipe the `echo` output to `pkexec tee -a file` to append it to a file requiring elevated permissions: **`echo -e '\nwl2k something\n' | pkexec tee -a /etc/ax25/axports`**

Comment: The question seems to be using "ask user for sudo to make the change" as a shorthand to "request authentication to run the command with administrative privileges". The `echo` command needs no special privileges, but writing to a specific file does. So `echo -e '\nwl2k something\n' | pkexec tee -a /etc/ax25/axports` is what the question seems to be looking for.

Comment: @telcoM You're correct of course. I just saw the `>>` redirect to a root-owned location, which of course never works, and gave the `sudo tee` method as the fix. I'll edit the answer.